# Safari css issues (negative margin?)

Tags: html, css, safari, margin

I have this issue in Safari:
[image]

I also create a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hbadvb02/6/ for play with this.

It works in Edge, IE, Chrome and Firefox ... and really I don't understand. It's very frustrating.

I have trying to use `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` but nothing.

Comment: On my computer, the fiddle only produces a blank screen with the "Utenti online" block at the bottom.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didnt specified. My fault. Click on "Utenti Online" then on "Pippo" or "Pluto"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
.zchead {
  margin-left: -1px;
  margin-top: -26px;
  height: 32px;
  width: @zc-width - 1px;
  line-height: 26px;
  background: @zc-background;
  padding: 2px 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
}
```

try to remove fixed position and it should works
(not tested)